# My command KeyGesture only works after I click the button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I have an 'Open Project' button, that when clicked, opens a File dialog and allows the user to select a file. I have added a command so the user can also use 'Ctrl + O' to be able to select a file.

The problem is that when I first run the application, if I haven't clicked the button yet, the KeyGesture will not open the File Dialog, but if I click the button and close the File Dialog, the 'Ctrl + O' then works.

This is the code in my xaml:

```
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        CommandBinding Command="local:ButtonCommands.OpenProject"    CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

This is my ButtonsCommand class:

public static RoutedUICommand OpenProject {  get; set; }

```
static ButtonCommands()
{
    InputGestureCollection input = new InputGestureCollection();
    KeyGesture shortkey = new KeyGesture(Key.O, ModifierKeys.Control);
    input.Add(shortkey);

    OpenProject = new RoutedUICommand("Open Project", "OpenProject", typeof(ButtonCommands), input);
}
```

This is my view code behind:

```
public void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Command != null)
    {
        if (Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter))
        {
            Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }
    }            
}
```

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

```
private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Aztec files (*.oipx) |*.oipx";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        ProjectDataProvider.Instance.OpenDBandGetData(openFileDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to check

```cs
    private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the button is focused
    e.CanExecute = btnOpenFile.IsKeyboardFocusWithin;
}
```

or ty to check

```xml
<Button Command="local:ButtonCommands.OpenProject" Click="btnOpenFile_Click">Open Project</Button>
```